# How to setup interfaces file to connect the Raspbian to a PC via SSH and Internet at the same time?

Tags: linux, ssh

How can I setup interfaces file to be able to connect the Raspberry pi to the internet (4g USB modem) and at the same time to a PC via SSH (ethernet).

My interface file look like this (/etc/network/interface):

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf looks as follows:-

```
       interface eth0
       static ip_address=10.1.1.30/24
       static routers=10.1.1.1
       static domain_name_servers=10.1.1.1
```

I am able to connect via SSH but I lose the internet connection.

Comment: AND I'm not sure I understand why you have a problem. I can connect to the internet and other local LAN PCs (as part of 192.168.1.*) from my Rpi. Can you restore to the std install? It should just work (or I don't understand you Q). (But this is still off-topic). Good luck!

Comment: I think I miss "auto eth0". i will try that (I asked to move this Q btw).

Comment: It doesn't work. I am not able to connect via ssh to a pc (ethernet) and have internet via 4g USB modem at the same time.

Comment: Please describe your minimal physical setup for this problem, i.e. `externalnternetConnection->4GBUSBmodem->RPi->{PC1,PC2,...}`.. (**by editing your Q, don't add this info as a comment!!** :-) ) . Don't you have a router or switch in there someplace? Good luck.

Comment: If you keep "auto lo" and add "auto eth0", does that solve your problem?
Don't disable the loop back interface by removing "auto lo".

Comment: If you hadn't fiddled with the `interfaces` file it would work. It doesn't say **# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'** for no reason. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Anders if i keep "auto lo" and add "auto eth0" just the ethernet connection works. So I don't get Internet just SSH.

Comment: I updated my setup changing the dhcpcd.conf  file ans leaving interfaces by default but I have the same behavior. I am able to connect via SSH but I lose the internet connection.